# What's the logic behind macOS Ventura having 6 folders which appear to be named Mail in ~/Library/Containers?

Tags: macos, finder, ventura

I recently moved from a Mac running Mojave to one running Ventura 13.4.1 and am experiencing a bit of upgrade whiplash.

Today I found myself in `~/Library/Containers` and noticed there are 6 folders named Mail.

[image: Screenshot of six Mail folders in home directory]

Get Info shows me they all actually have different names.  But I don't know what the utility is of having them all "look like" they have the same name in Finder. Can someone point me in the right direction, as internet searching hasn't offered any clues.

[update]

```
ber@rolo ~ % cd Library/Containers; ls -ld Mail* 
zsh: no matches found: Mail*
ber@rolo Containers %
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you’re trying to solve? Asking what’s the logic is borderline off topic here as we don’t host questions asking why Apple does things…

Answer (score 10):

The folders are not named Mail, they are named specific things (as shown in Tetsujin's screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI7Aw.png)). These containers refer to different components in Mail.

The command line tool `mdls` will show you the finder name and the file system name and if set localized names of any folder / directory like these. When viewing a file/folder in finder you may not see all the details needed to understand the identity of some folders like these.

The reason they are all labeled the same is because Finder replaces the bundle IDs and other programmatically generated folder names with the actual application name. In the case of Mail, multiple things resolve to the name Mail so this effect is observed.

There is no malfunction here, aside from the lack of foresight to further disambiguate these folders. Typically, users do no need to visit the containers directory so it's a non-issue. If you do need to determine which one you're looking in, that's easy enough with the Get Info menu which shows the fully specified name.